# Need to draw a line between two points on the web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

My situation here is that, I have asp `Imagebuttons` on my web page which are dynamically generated. When I Click on one `ImageButton` I see the other dynamically created `ImageButtons` which are related to it (Relation is maintained in Database). Now when I clicked on any `Imagebutton` I need to draw a line between the clicked `ImageButton` and the related `Imagebuttons` which get displayed on the web page. As I am working with web application and not windows application I cannot access the drawing library. So is there any way to draw lines using javascript or jquery. Everything here click event, `Imagebuttons` are dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of options:
http://jsbin.com/enime3/1/edit
http://raphaeljs.com/
http://www.amaslo.com/2012/06/drawing-diagonal-line-in-htmlcssjs-with.html

Similar questions on SO:
[How to draw a line between 2 elements using JQuery and refreshing that line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712189/how-to-draw-a-line-between-2-elements-using-jquery-and-refreshing-that-line)

[Easiest way to "draw" simple lines over an image with jQuery and save to Rails DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030441/easiest-way-to-draw-simple-lines-over-an-image-with-jquery-and-save-to-rails-d)

Comment: thanks a lot. 1 more thing, without clicking the dynamic images can i know the co-ordinates of the imagebuttons(top,Left). On page load my ImageButtons are getting placed on the web page dynamically. So once i find the co-ordinates I can draw a line between them.

Comment: @AnkurDeshpande take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002934/jquery-x-y-document-coordinates-of-dom-object  or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery